# aiohttp concurrent GET requests lead to ClientConnectorError(8, 'nodename nor servname provided, or not known')

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am stumped by a problem seemingly related to `asyncio` + `aiohttp` whereby, when sending a large number of concurrent GET requests, over 85% of the requests raise an `aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError` exception that ultimately stems from

```
socket.gaierror(8, 'nodename nor servname provided, or not known')
```

while sending single GET requests or doing the underlying DNS resolution on the host/port does not raise this exception.

While in my real code I'm doing a good amount of customization such as using a custom [`TCPConnector`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/connector.py) instance, I can reproduce the issue using just the "default" `aiohttp` class instances & arguments, exactly as below.

I've followed the traceback and the root of the exception is related to DNS resolution.  It comes from the [`_create_direct_connection`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/18a64b2309a1d8aa32f61f4030a5d05560f8de91/aiohttp/connector.py#L933) method of `aiohttp.TCPConnector`, which calls [`._resolve_host()`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/18a64b2309a1d8aa32f61f4030a5d05560f8de91/aiohttp/connector.py#L773).

I have also tried:

- Using (and not using) `aiodns`
- `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`
- Using `family=socket.AF_INET` as an argument to `TCPConnector` (though I am fairly sure this is used by `aiodns` anyway).  This uses `2` rather than the default int `0` to that param
- With `ssl=True` and `ssl=False`

All to no avail.

---

Full code to reproduce is below.  The input URLs are at https://gist.github.com/bsolomon1124/fc625b624dd26ad9b5c39ccb9e230f5a.

```
import asyncio
import itertools

import aiohttp
import aiohttp.client_exceptions

from yarl import URL

ua = itertools.cycle(
    (
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; ko; rv:1.9.1b2) Gecko/20081201 Firefox/60.0",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
    )
)

async def get(url, session) -> str:
    async with await session.request(
        "GET",
        url=url,
        raise_for_status=True,
        headers={'User-Agent': next(ua)},
        ssl=False
    ) as resp:
        text = await resp.text(encoding="utf-8", errors="replace")
        print("Got text for URL", url)
        return text

async def bulk_get(urls) -> list:
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        htmls = await asyncio.gather(
            *(
                get(url=url, session=session)
                for url in urls
            ),
            return_exceptions=True
        )
        return htmls


# See https://gist.github.com/bsolomon1124/fc625b624dd26ad9b5c39ccb9e230f5a
with open("/path/to/urls.txt") as f:
    urls = tuple(URL(i.strip()) for i in f)

res = asyncio.run(bulk_get(urls))  # urls: Tuple[yarl.URL]

c = 0
for i in res:
    if isinstance(i, aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError):
        print(i)
        c += 1

print(c)  # 21205 !!!!! (85% failure rate)
print(len(urls))  # 24934
```

Printing each exception string from `res` looks like:

```
Cannot connect to host sigmainvestments.com:80 ssl:False [nodename nor servname provided, or not known]
Cannot connect to host giaoducthoidai.vn:443 ssl:False [nodename nor servname provided, or not known]
Cannot connect to host chauxuannguyen.org:80 ssl:False [nodename nor servname provided, or not known]
Cannot connect to host www.baohomnay.com:443 ssl:False [nodename nor servname provided, or not known]
Cannot connect to host www.soundofhope.org:80 ssl:False [nodename nor servname provided, or not known]
# And so on...
```

---

What's frustrating is that I can `ping` these hosts with no problem and even call the underlying `._resolve_host()`:

Bash/shell:

```
 [~/] $ ping -c 5 www.hongkongfp.com
PING www.hongkongfp.com (104.20.232.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 104.20.232.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=56 time=11.667 ms
64 bytes from 104.20.232.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=12.169 ms
64 bytes from 104.20.232.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=12.135 ms
64 bytes from 104.20.232.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=12.235 ms
64 bytes from 104.20.232.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=14.252 ms

--- www.hongkongfp.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 11.667/12.492/14.252/0.903 ms
```

Python:

```
In [1]: import asyncio 
   ...: from aiohttp.connector import TCPConnector 
   ...: from clipslabapp.ratemgr import default_aiohttp_tcpconnector 
   ...:  
   ...:  
   ...: async def main(): 
   ...:     conn = default_aiohttp_tcpconnector() 
   ...:     i = await asyncio.create_task(conn._resolve_host(host='www.hongkongfp.com', port=443)) 
   ...:     return i 
   ...:  
   ...: i = asyncio.run(main())                                                                                                                               

In [2]: i                                                                                                                                                     
Out[2]: 
[{'hostname': 'www.hongkongfp.com',
  'host': '104.20.232.8',
  'port': 443,
  'family': <AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>,
  'proto': 6,
  'flags': <AddressInfo.AI_NUMERICHOST: 4>},
 {'hostname': 'www.hongkongfp.com',
  'host': '104.20.233.8',
  'port': 443,
  'family': <AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>,
  'proto': 6,
  'flags': <AddressInfo.AI_NUMERICHOST: 4>}]
```

---

My setup:

- Python 3.7.1
- aiohttp 3.5.4
- Occurs on Mac OSX High Sierra and Ubuntu 18.04

---

Information on the exception itself:

The exception is `aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError`, which wraps `socket.gaierror` as the underlying `OSError`.

Since I have `return_exceptions=True` in `asyncio.gather()`, I can get the exception instances themselves for inspection.  Here is one example:

```
In [18]: i
Out[18]:
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError(8,
                                               'nodename nor servname provided, or not known')

In [19]: i.host, i.port
Out[19]: ('www.hongkongfp.com', 443)

In [20]: i._conn_key
Out[20]: ConnectionKey(host='www.hongkongfp.com', port=443, is_ssl=True, ssl=False, proxy=None, proxy_auth=None, proxy_headers_hash=None)

In [21]: i._os_error
Out[21]: socket.gaierror(8, 'nodename nor servname provided, or not known')

In [22]: raise i.with_traceback(i.__traceback__)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Scripts/python/projects/clab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py in _create_direct_connection(self, req, traces, timeout, client_error)
    954                 port,
--> 955                 traces=traces), loop=self._loop)
    956         except OSError as exc:

~/Scripts/python/projects/clab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py in _resolve_host(self, host, port, traces)
    824                 addrs = await \
--> 825                     self._resolver.resolve(host, port, family=self._family)
    826                 if traces:

~/Scripts/python/projects/clab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/resolver.py in resolve(self, host, port, family)
     29         infos = await self._loop.getaddrinfo(
---> 30             host, port, type=socket.SOCK_STREAM, family=family)
     31

/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py in getaddrinfo(self, host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    772         return await self.run_in_executor(
--> 773             None, getaddr_func, host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    774

/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py in run(self)
     56         try:
---> 57             result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
     58         except BaseException as exc:

/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    747     addrlist = []
--> 748     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    749         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ClientConnectorError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-72402d8c3b31> in <module>
----> 1 raise i.with_traceback(i.__traceback__)

<ipython-input-1-2bc0f5172de7> in get(url, session)
     19         raise_for_status=True,
     20         headers={'User-Agent': next(ua)},
---> 21         ssl=False
     22     ) as resp:
     23         return await resp.text(encoding="utf-8", errors="replace")

~/Scripts/python/projects/clab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py in _request(self, method, str_or_url, params, data, json, cookies, headers, skip_auto_headers, auth, allow_redirects, max_redirects, compress, chunked, expect100, raise_for_status, read_until_eof, proxy, proxy_auth, timeout, verify_ssl, fingerprint, ssl_context, ssl, proxy_headers, trace_request_ctx)
    474                                 req,
    475                                 traces=traces,
--> 476                                 timeout=real_timeout
    477                             )
    478                     except asyncio.TimeoutError as exc:

~/Scripts/python/projects/clab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py in connect(self, req, traces, timeout)
    520
    521             try:
--> 522                 proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
    523                 if self._closed:
    524                     proto.close()

~/Scripts/python/projects/clab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py in _create_connection(self, req, traces, timeout)
    852         else:
    853             _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(
--> 854                 req, traces, timeout)
    855
    856         return proto

~/Scripts/python/projects/clab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py in _create_direct_connection(self, req, traces, timeout, client_error)
    957             # in case of proxy it is not ClientProxyConnectionError
    958             # it is problem of resolving proxy ip itself
--> 959             raise ClientConnectorError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
    960
    961         last_exc = None  # type: Optional[Exception]

ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host www.hongkongfp.com:443 ssl:False [nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

---

Why do I not think this is a problem with DNS resolution at the OS level itself?

I can successfully ping the IP address of my ISP’s DNS Servers, which are given in (Mac OSX) System Preferences > Network > DNS:

```
 [~/] $ ping -c 2 75.75.75.75
PING 75.75.75.75 (75.75.75.75): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 75.75.75.75: icmp_seq=0 ttl=57 time=16.478 ms
64 bytes from 75.75.75.75: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=21.042 ms

--- 75.75.75.75 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 16.478/18.760/21.042/2.282 ms
 [~/] $ ping -c 2 75.75.76.76
PING 75.75.76.76 (75.75.76.76): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 75.75.76.76: icmp_seq=0 ttl=54 time=33.904 ms
64 bytes from 75.75.76.76: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=32.788 ms

--- 75.75.76.76 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 32.788/33.346/33.904/0.558 ms

 [~/] $ ping6 -c 2 2001:558:feed::1
PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) 2601:14d:8b00:7d0:6587:7cfc:e2cc:82a0 --> 2001:558:feed::1
16 bytes from 2001:558:feed::1, icmp_seq=0 hlim=57 time=14.927 ms
16 bytes from 2001:558:feed::1, icmp_seq=1 hlim=57 time=14.585 ms

--- 2001:558:feed::1 ping6 statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/std-dev = 14.585/14.756/14.927/0.171 ms
 [~/] $ ping6 -c 2 2001:558:feed::2
PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) 2601:14d:8b00:7d0:6587:7cfc:e2cc:82a0 --> 2001:558:feed::2
16 bytes from 2001:558:feed::2, icmp_seq=0 hlim=54 time=12.694 ms
16 bytes from 2001:558:feed::2, icmp_seq=1 hlim=54 time=11.555 ms

--- 2001:558:feed::2 ping6 statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/std-dev = 11.555/12.125/12.694/0.569 ms
```

Comment: I've tested your code and had only 9 failures. And these 9 website don't work really. So I believe this is not a problem about your program but your network environment. Maybe your ISP's DNS server bans you because you require too fast. A easy way to test is: First, modify your program to only do dns solving instead of a whole requests. Second, use a vpn, as it will forward all your connections including dns ones.

Comment: Or you can try `1.1.1.1` as your dns server.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some further investigation, this issue does not appear to be directly caused by `aiohttp`/`asyncio` but rather limitations/limits stemming from both:

- The capacity/rate-limiting of your DNS Servers
- The max number of open files at the system level.

Firstly, for those looking to get some beefed-up DNS servers (I will probably not go that route), the big-name options seem to be:

- 1.1.1.1 (Cloudflare)
- 8.8.8.8 (Google Public DNS)
- Amazon Route 53

([Good intro to DNS](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/what-is-dns/) for those like me for whom network concepts are lacking.)

The first thing that I did was to run the above on a beefed-up AWS EC2 instance - h1.16xlarge running Ubuntu which is IO optimized.  I can't say this in itself helped, but it certainly cannot hurt.  I'm not too familiar with the default DNS server used by an EC2 instance, but the OSError with errno == 8 from above went away when replicating the above script.

However, that presented a new exception in its place, OSError with code 24, "Too many open files."  My hotfix solution (not arguing this is the most sustainable or safest) was to increase the max file limits.  I did this via:

```
sudo vim /etc/security/limits.conf
# Add these lines
root    soft    nofile  100000
root    hard    nofile  100000
ubuntu    soft    nofile  100000
ubuntu    hard    nofile  100000

sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf
# Add this line
fs.file-max = 2097152

sudo sysctl -p

sudo vim /etc/pam.d/commmon_session
# Add this line
session required pam_limits.so

sudo reboot
```

I am admittedly feeling around in the dark, but coupling this with `asyncio.Semaphore(1024)` (example [here](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html)) led to exactly 0 of the either 2 exceptions above being raised:

```
# Then call this from bulk_get with asyncio.Sempahore(n)
async def bounded_get(sem, url, session) -> str:
    async with sem:
        return await get(url, session)
```

Of the ~25k input URLs, only ~100 GET requests returned exceptions, mainly due to those websites being legitimately broken, with total time to completion coming in within a few minutes, acceptable in my opinion.

Comment: You could fix the max concurrent file descriptor problem by either batching or setting up a `asyncio` semaphore or the bounded semaphore. Configure the semaphore with the max number of concurrent requests to allow and add a `async with` to execute each request under the semaphore lock. That way you can schedule a whole lot but keep the number of concurrent in-flight requests limited to a predefined maximum.

Comment: Yes - thanks, I've done that as well @user268396.  See the last part of my answer above

Comment: Oh cool. Note that with the semaphore being set appropriately you no longer need to fiddle with the limits (which are there to keep resource consumption in check). Also if for some reason you didn't want to do the semaphore *and* you didn't want to do this limits thing globally you could use `ulimit` instead.